# subtração de meses com erros em 31 dias (strtotime)

Tags: php, data

Estou desenvolvendo um gráfico utilizando a biblioteca `chart.js`. Está funcionando perfeitamente.
Acontece que hoje, mês de Maio com 31 dias, as subtrações dos meses acontece de forma errada.

```
$mhoje = date("M");

$m1 = date('M', strtotime(' - 1 month'));
$em1 = ucfirst(strftime('%b', strtotime($m1)));

echo "$mhoje / $m1 / $em1"; // May / May / Mai
```

Ou seja, `hoje menos 1 month` ainda é Maio.

Utilizo apenas `date("M")` pois preciso apenas do nome do mês e não das datas, mas já testei completo, como `date("Y-M-d")`.

Nos outros dias isso funciona perfeitamente.

Preciso obter os últimos 12 meses a partir da data de hoje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme a documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Para obter o ultimo dia de um mês deve-se usar `last day`, você pode ver no link da documentação aonde esta escrito "Day-based Notations", ou abaixo:

| Formato | Descrição | Examplos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `yesterday` | Meia-noite de ontem | `yesterday 14:00` |
| `midnight` | A hora é configurada para 00:00:00 |  |
| `today` | A hora é configurada para 00:00:00 |  |
| `now` | Agora - isto é simplesmente ignorado |  |
| `noon` | A hora é configurada para 12:00:00 | `yesterday noon` |
| `tomorrow` | Meia-noite de amanhã |  |
| `back of` hour | 15 minutos após a hora informada | `back of 7pm`, `back of 15` |
| `front of` hour | 15 minutos antes da hora informada | `front of 5am`, `front of 23` |
| `first day of` | Define o dia para o primeiro dia do mês atual. Essa frase é usada de melhor forma, junto com um nome de mês. | `first day of January 2008` |
| `last day of` | Define o dia para o último do mês corrente. Essa frase é usada de melhor forma, junto com um nome de mês. | `last day of next month` |
| ordinal space dayname space `of` | Calcula o número ordinal x-th da semana do mês corrente. | `first sat of July 2008` |
| `last` space dayname space `of` | Calcular o último dia da semana do mês corrente. | `last sat of July 2008` |
| `number space? (unit | 'week')` | Manipula porções de tempo relativas onde o valor seja um número. | `+5 weeks`, `12 day`, `-7 weekdays` |
| ordinal space unit | Manipula porções de tempo relativas onde o valor seja um texto. | `fifth day`, `second month` |
| `ago` | Nega todos os valores das porções de tempo relativas anteriores. | `2 days ago`, `8 days ago 14:00`, `2 months 5 days ago`, `2 months ago 5 days`, `2 days ago` |
| dayname | Move para o próximo dia deste nome. | `Monday` |
| reltext space `week` | Manipula o formato especial `weekday + last/this/next week`. | `Monday next week` |

E para obter o mês anterior deve usar `previous month`, na documentação localiza aonde esta escrito **Used Symbols**, ou abaixo:

| Descrição | Formato |
| --- | --- |
| `dayname` | `sunday` | `monday` | `tuesday` | `wednesday` | `thursday` | `friday` | `saturday` | `sun` | `mon` | `tue` | `wed` | `thu` | `fri` | `sat` |
| `daytext` | `weekday` | `weekdays` |
| `number` | `[+-]?[0-9]+` |
| `ordinal` | `first` | `second` | `third` | `fourth` | `fifth` | `sixth` | `seventh` | `eighth` | `ninth` | `tenth` | `eleventh` | `twelfth` | `next` | `last` | `previous` | `this` |
| reltext | `next` | `last` | `previous` | `this` |
| space | `[ \t]+` |
| unit | `(('sec' | 'second' | 'min' | 'minute' | 'hour' | 'day' | 'fortnight' | 'forthnight' | 'month' | 'year') 's'?)` | `weeks` | `daytext` |

Logo você pode combinar ambos em:

```
last day of previous month
```

Traduzindo, "o ultimo dia do mês anterior". O uso de `-1 month` deve ser devido a considerar **30 dias** como a unidade de valor, veja o teste online: https://ideone.com/CwMD39

Comment: Eu testei e funcionou. Acredito que eu falhei na formulação da pergunta. Eu preciso obter dos últimos 12 meses. `last day of previous month` eu obtenho o mês anterior corretamente. Mas quando preciso obter de todo o ano?

Comment: @JuniorLike faça um loop, se o mês atual é 5 você vai fazer 4 loops executando o tempo relativo obtido e pegando todos ultimos dias de todos 4 meses anteriores, dá para pegar o mês atual em formato de numero usando `$mesatual = date('n')`, então salva o valor em uma variavel e faz -1 e joga em um loop `for ($i = $mesatual - 1; $i > 0; $i--) { ... }`

Comment: Obrigado pela ampla e rápida resposta!

Comment: @JuniorLike no strtotime no segundo parametro vá passando o valor da ultima data obtida do loop anterior, e pode salvar em um array a cada loop.

Comment: Sim, vi seu código mas pensei em montar um array, acho que vai ser melhor pra eu trabalhar com a biblioteca.

Comment: no seu `for` de exemplo ele sempre para no mês 1. Não volta para o mes 12, 11 e assim por diante. Você poderia me ajudar, por favor? Ou abro uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @JuniorLike como eu disse no comment anterior, tem que salvar o valor retornado do strtotime em uma variavel, que vai ser um "Unix timestamp", e colocar no segundo parametro do proximo strtotime.